# Убрать всё в запросе после ***.html через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго времени суток.

Необходимо удалять непонятные довески, которые которых изначально в ссылке нет, но пользователи переходят по ссылкам, оставленным непонятно как. Пример: ...test.html , а переходят `..test.html'` `..test.html\` `..test.html5867`

Как отсечь все, что находится после `.html` и соответственно переадресовать на статью.

Пробовал так, но что-то намудрил.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html).*$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Пользовательский поиск гугл стал некорректно работать. Видимо что-то я напутал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет работать:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+?)\.html.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

Проверить онлайн: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Также см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703566/htaccess-strip-everything-after-html

Comment: Спасибо большое! Исчерпывающий ответ :-)

Answer (score -1):

Данный код не убирает вопросительный знак и символы после него после `html`. Подскажите, как убрать абсолютно все символы после `html`.

Comment: Это  не ответ. Задайте новый вопрос.